# pgfplotstable: How to output a table with some empty cells in header row?

Tags: pgfplotstable

I want to output a simple table using `pgfplotstable` with first two cells in the header row are empty as given in the following figure:

[image: table with first two empty cells in header row]

What is the simplest solution for this?

Regards, Jamil

Comment: Use the `tabular`environment and leave the cells empty e.g. `& & x & y`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short compilable code you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

The [LaTex wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) gives a good example of this using `multicolumn`.  Here is a modified version of their example:

```
\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|c|c}
\cline{3-5}
& & \multicolumn{3}{ c| }{blah} \\ \cline{3-5}
& & x & y & z \\ \cline{1-5}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{var1} & a & 2 & 0 & 1    \\ \cline{1-5}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{var2} & b & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ \cline{1-5}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{var3} & c & 3 & 1 & 1 \\ \cline{1-5}
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Yes of course :-) it is simple, but the OP want use `pgfplotstable, which is a little more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all of you who tried to help me. I have come to the solution using pgfplotstable. here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,titlepage]{article}
\pagestyle{headings}
%\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%\pagestyle{arabic}

%\usepackage[a4paper,left=1.25in,right=1.25in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
%\usepackage[left=1cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,footnotesep=0.5cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage[a4paper,left=2.0cm,right=2.0cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=4.5cm]{geometry} % from Dr. Tahir
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
%\setlength{\mathindent}{4cm}%

\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{subcaption}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% fr*om pgfplotstable.pdf
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
% recommended:
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% from pgfplots.pdf
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm, compat=1.3}% <-- moves axis labels near ticklabels (respects tick label widths)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}


%%%%%%% pgfplotstable code start %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
col sep=semicolon,
row sep=\\,
columns/0/.style={string type,column name={}},
columns/1/.style={string type,column name={}},
columns/value/.style={fixed,fixed zerofill,dec sep align,precision=6,column name={$\mathbf{X}$}},
columns/sd/.style={fixed,fixed zerofill,dec sep align,precision=6,column name={$\mathbf{Y}$}},
]{
   ;   ;   x;   y\\
{$Var1\ name$}; $a$ ;1;2\\
{$Var2\ name$}; $b$ ;3;4\\
{$Var3\ name$}; $c$ ;5;6\\
}
%%%%%%% pgfplotstable code end %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\end{document}
```

and here is the output (slightly different from the question but what I wanted exactly):

[image]

Regards,
Jamil